# VSIX: subscribe to command

Tags: vsx

How do I subscribe to a 3rdparty extension's command from my own VSIX extension? Such as OnClick event of an extension.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a command, you should be able to capture it using `DTE.Events.CommandEvents[commandGuid, commandId].BeforeExecute` (or `AfterExecute`). ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.events.commandevents.aspx))

If you do not know the ID and GUID you can subscribe to all commands (as both indexer parameters are optional), add logging of ID/GUID, then use the command you are interested in.

**Important Note:**
I believe you have to keep a reference to `DTE.Events.CommandEvents[commandGuid, commandId]` somewhere so it will not be garbage collected. Otherwise you may lose your subscription.

Comment: As Andrey said, keep a ref of CommandEvents object you obtain otherwise your may lose event subscriptions.